# Attribute of 'this' object is showing undefined inside $.each

Tags: jquery, each

here is the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6eqMn/524/

**JS** part:

```
$("#divProcedureCodes").append("<TABLE><TBODY><TR ID='divtr2' STATUS='Map'><TD STYLE='WIDT`enter code here`H: 20px'></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE>");

function allChargesMapped() {
    var retval = true;   
        $.each($("#divProcedureCodes tr"), function (index, value) {
        if (this.status == "Map") {
            retval = false;
            return false;
        }
    });
    return retval;
}
var ret = allChargesMapped();
alert(ret);
alert(document.getElementById("divtr2").getAttribute("status"));
```

**HTML** part:

```
<DIV ID="divProcedureCodes"> </DIV>
```

Comment: oops sorry, didn't format properly the first line. Jsfiddle is fine though.

Comment: $("#divProcedureCodes").append("<TABLE><TBODY><TR ID='divtr2' STATUS='Map'><TD STYLE='WIDTH: 20px'></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE>");

Comment: return value is true instead of false. The condition (this.status == "Map") is returning false incorrecly.

Comment: `STATUS`isn't valid attribute so don't expect it to be mapped as DOM node property. Use e.g `data-status` instead and check for `this.dataset.status`   http://jsfiddle.net/6eqMn/530/  BTW, avoid using upercased string for DOM markup, that's just horrible imho

Comment: @A.Wolff I am doing jasmine testing for the method. I cannot change the original production code. The html I am appending is taken from IE 8's (the app runs only in IE 8) dev tools page. Is there any way I can test this(the false scenario).

Comment: Ok so IE8 doesn't support HTML5 `data-*` attributes, you can use instead `$(this).attr('status') == "Map"`: http://jsfiddle.net/6eqMn/531/

Comment: @A.Wolff Thanks for that man. Though I can't change the original code, I can suggest them this.

Answer (score 0):

Use `getAttribute()` function for this. You cannot get it in the usual way as for the normal attributes.

```
this.getAttribute('status')
```

```js
    var aq = $("#divProcedureCodes tr");
    $("#divProcedureCodes").append("<TABLE><TBODY><TR ID='divtr2' STATUS='Map'><TD STYLE='WIDTH: 20px'></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE>");

    function allChargesMapped() {
      var retval = true;
      $.each($("#divProcedureCodes tr"), function(index, value) {
        alert(this.getAttribute('status'));
        if (this.getAttribute('status') == "Map") {
          retval = false;
          return false;
        }
      });
      return retval;
    }
    var ret = allChargesMapped();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<DIV ID="divProcedureCodes"></DIV>
```